# How to read from txt file character by character and line by line c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create multiple binary trees from reading from a single txt file. To do this I have to read each character on a line, create the tree, then move to the next line to create another tree.  My current code is grabbing input line by line and I'm not sure how to change this?

This is what I have now:

```
int main()
{
    vector <BinaryTree <string> > BT;
        int iteration = 0;

        string line;
        ifstream myfile("input.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while(getline (myfile, line))
            {
                BinaryTree <string> temptree;
                BT.push_back(temptree);
                BT[iteration].InsertData(line);

                cout << "Preorder: ";
                BT[iteration].PrintPreorder();
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Inorder: ";
                BT[iteration].PrintInorder();
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Postorder: ";
                BT[iteration].PrintPostorder();
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Reverse Inorder: ";
                BT[iteration].PrintReverseInorder();
                cout << endl;

                BT[iteration].PrintPrintTree();
                cout << endl;
                iteration++;


            myfile.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
while (myfile>> std::noskipws >> c)
{
    if(c == '\n')
        printf("new line\n");
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

use the `operator>>` to read character by character and then test if you get a line break, `std::noskipws` means initial whitespace characters are valid content to be extracted. Or you can also use [`ifstream.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) like this:

```
char c;
while (myfile.get(c))
{
    if(c == '\n')
        printf("new line\n");
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Comment: you can also use `char c = ifs.get()`